# Is an email mailto link a valid URL?

Tags: email, url, syntax, uri

According to the URL syntax there are supposed to be slashes after the colon following the protocol. An email link, e.g.

```
mailto:bla@shoe.com
```

, however, does not contain these slashes.

Can these addresses be considered valid URLs ?

Comment: Which URL syntax? There are different forms of URLs as visible between the mailto and a http

Comment: Please refer this [link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/)

Comment: There is, as far as I know, one URL syntax:  RFC 3986 (2005)

Comment: @Nayana_Das I do not want to 'learn' the email-syntax. I want to know whether it can be considered valid in regards with the URL-syntax.

Comment: Just as a note: mailto URN is covered by RFC 2368 and RFC 6068.

Comment: Considering most URNs require `URN:` to prefix their schemas, does that mean that `mailTo:` should be written as `URN:mailTo:`?

Comment: Mailto is not a URN, but a URL. However the distinction between URN and URL is actually no longer really made. Check this wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The URI standard is [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66) which currently maps to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

The double slash you know from some URIs (e.g., from HTTP URIs like `http://example.com/`) precedes the [*authority* component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2), but this *authority* component is [not required](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) by the generic URI syntax (only [*scheme*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1) and [*path*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) are).

So, the [`mailto` URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068) is not using the *authority* component, and therefore there is no `//` after the *scheme* component.

Comment: You forgot the conclusion :)

Comment: You are right. But I must say that the wording of the standard is quite obfuscated. e.g. " The scheme and path components are required, though the path may be empty (no characters)" , this means path is not required. Would "someprototol:" then be considered a valid URI also?

Comment: @dstibbe: Yes, I think so. However, this is the generic syntax, so a specific URI scheme may further restrict this, e.g. by requiring a certain component or disallowing empty pathes.