# Why does http:// contain two slashes and file:/// three in a browser navigation bar?

Tags: url, web

Why does `http://` contain two slashes—is that just a standard for a URL, or does it have any logical meaning? And why does `file:///` contain three slashes, as in `file:///C:/a.html`?

Comment: [superuser.com: Why do file URLs start with 3 slashes?](http://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes)

Comment: Is "[Because Tim Berners-Lee told you to](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)" an acceptable reason?

Answer (score 32):

The [authority component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2) of a URI has to be preceded by `//`:

> The authority component is preceded by a double slash ("//") […]

This is also [why not all URIs contain the double slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27151227/1591669): because not all URIs have an authority component (e.g., URIs using the `mailto` scheme, the `xmpp` scheme, etc.).

---

If you wonder why the double slash instead of something else (or nothing) was chosen for (HTTP) URIs, see Tim Berners-Lee’s FAQ [Why the //, #, etc?](https://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/FAQ.html#etc) → *What is the history of the //?*

tl;dr: He copied the filename syntax which [Apollo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Computer) used.

By the way, he regrets that choice:

> I have to say that now I regret that the syntax is so clumsy. I would like `http://www.example.com/foo/bar/baz` to be just written `http:com/example/foo/bar/baz` where the client would figure out that `www.example.com` existed and was the server to contact. But it is too late now.

Comment: Might be some regret, but it does make it easier to at a glance isolate the domain from the protocol, in my opinion

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned in this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/352134):

> The complete syntax is file://host/path.
>
> If the host is localhost, it can be omitted, resulting in
>   file:///path.

In other words, referring to files in your computer is just like referring to files in localhost.

Comment: then why `http://` contains two slashes or what does mean of first two slashes in `file://` too?

Comment: From the following [Wikipedia: File_URI_Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) , it is explained that it is in the following format:  `file://<host>/<resource>`, if the `<host>` portion is left blank, the other `/` following it needs to remain thus `file:///` is the same as `file://localhost/` . Most browser url's are in the format of `<sheme>://<host>/<resource>`

Comment: @SanuelJackson why everyone is repeating same words? I'm asking what does mean of first two slashes? `file://` or `http://`?

Comment: @LetDoit - those are the characters chosen as the designated separator when drafting the rfc for uri format. A uri can also contain other data such as username and password :  `<scheme>://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<resource>` is a more "complete" example. If you notice there are more than one method where `:` would appear before a `/` so I imagine that would be why they denoted `//` following the first `:` to make it easier to parse. Generally though, the concept is what the original author of the rfc decided on. Similarly, spintax uses `{<word>|<word>}` as that was their choice.