# 3 or 5 slashes for cross-browser file URI

Tags: uri, local, unc, file-uri

I am using `<a href="file:...">` links inside an Intranet for local folder access.

What bothers me is the amount of slashes I have to write in those URI for cross-browser compatibility.

```
Internet Explorer 11.904.16299.0

   file://server/share/path/to/file ok
  file:///server/share/path/to/file not working
 file:////server/share/path/to/file ok
file://///server/share/path/to/file ok

Edge 41.16299.820.0

   file://server/share/path/to/file ok
  file:///server/share/path/to/file not working
 file:////server/share/path/to/file ok
file://///server/share/path/to/file ok

Firefox 60.0 with Local Filesystem Links Extension

   file://server/share/path/to/file not working
  file:///server/share/path/to/file not working
 file:////server/share/path/to/file not working
file://///server/share/path/to/file ok
```

When I look for answers in Stack Overflow or similar, I end up in those posts, saying that the correct amount is 3 slashes.

- https://superuser.com/questions/352133/why-do-file-urls-start-with-3-slashes
- [Why does http:// contain two slashes and file:/// three in a browser navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36433409/why-http-contain-two-slashes-and-file-three-in-browser)

I write this question and answer it in case someone gets confused like I did.

Comment: What does "KO" mean? That is does not work? I never saw "KO" as meaning "not OK" and I read the web since it started.

Comment: @DavidBalažic can't say if it's a gallicism or not... but yes it meant "not working" to me. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to distinct 2 types of `<a href="file:...>"` links: local paths and UNC paths.

**Local path URI**

This is the path to a file accessible inside the client machine, either because the file is inside its local storage or because it is accessible through a **mapped drive** / **mounted folder**.

Those URI take 3 slashes:

- `file:///p:/share/path/to/file`
- `file:////mnt/share/path/to/file`

The fourth slash for the second example is the UNIX root `/`.

**UNC path URI**

The format I show in my question, `file://///server/share/path/to/file`, is known as an UNC path.

This is a path accessible from the client machine through an **internal URI**, like `my.server.com`. In Windows, for example, this is when you use the server URI to access the file, not its mapped drive letter.

Those URI take 5 slashes:

- `file://///my.server.com/share/path/to/file`

The links that helped me answer my question:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention

The "about" section of the Firefox Local Filesystem Links Extension also talks about it:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/